# Optimization with trace and eigenvalues

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix with given eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ 
with $\vert\lambda_1\vert > \vert \lambda_2\vert>\cdots>\vert\lambda_n\vert$

How to find a matrix $\tilde{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with eigenvalues $\tilde\lambda_1,\tilde\lambda_2,\cdots,\tilde\lambda_n$ and $\vert\tilde\lambda_1\vert > \vert\tilde\lambda_2\vert>\cdots>\vert\tilde\lambda_n\vert$

such that:

$\tilde M \neq M$

and

$\vert  Tr(M) + Tr (\tilde M) \vert  \leq c \vert \tilde \lambda_1 + \lambda_1  \vert $

where $c \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $Tr$ is the trace operator.

Comment: How do you know that the eigenvalues are real? Is $M$ symmetric, are these the singular values, or do we only know it for $|\sigma_n|$? Also, what is $c$? certainly I can choose $c$ to be really large and this is trivial. Are we optimizing $c$?

Comment: Sorry, my question was badly formulated. The matrix M is only supposed to be symmetric and its eigenvalues are not the singular values. They are determined with a classical spectral decomposition of $M = TDT^{-1}$